# let 2 VMs talk to each other with NAT

Tags: network, virtualization

I am running two instances of [macosvm](https://github.com/s-u/macosvm) on a Ventura host (Apple Silicon) with NAT. Unfortunately, they don't see one another, presumably because **bridge100** members have **PRIVATE** flag. How can I remove this flag? Or is there something else I can do to connect the two machines together? The idea is to emulate a client/server setup for CI/CD.

---

I cannot use bridged network because of infrastructure limitations.

Comment: Please confirm this is on an Apple silicon Mac. If so, 1) VirtualBuddy is a more actively developed product, 2) I don't think what you want is possible under Apple virtualisation (I need a reference for this).

Comment: Ignore my point 2 above. I have now convinced myself that you can enable network connections between two VMs (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Use [VirtualBuddy](https://github.com/insidegui/VirtualBuddy) which is, I believe, the leading VM product for running macOS VMs on Apple silicon.  It is also under active development.

With VirtualBuddy (VB) I have created two macOS VMs called Sonoma-1 and Sonoma-2 with users gilby1 and gilby2.

Most importantly, VB gives the choice of NAT or Bridged networks.  A bridged network gets (via DHCP or static address) an IP address on the same network as the host.

The two virtual machines can communicate with each other. Firstly `ping` confirms basic network connectivity.

I enabled file sharing on Sonoma-1 and Sonoma-2 can connect to its shares.

Here is Sonoma-2 pinging Sonoma-1 (192.168.0.73) and Finder opening shared folders on Sonoma-1.

Given that I can ping and file share between my 2 virtual machines, I am sure you could configure any other network connectivity.

[image: VB]

Comment: Thanks, I know that with bridged network such communication works. But I have an infrastructure requirement for the VMs to work differently. The "easy" option is to use NAT. There is an alternative "unix socket" networking which can use a  [proxy](https://github.com/agraf/slirp-unix), but this, too, does not have examples of connecting 2 VMs on the same host.